# Batch copy files containing spaces

Tags: batch-file, copy

I just need quick input for the following command in batch:

```
for %%f in (%UserProfile%\Fonts\*.*tf) do if not exist "%SystemRoot%\Fonts\%%~nxf" xcopy %%f "%UserProfile%\Fonts2\" /Y
```

I want the script to copy all files, which are not already installed in the windows fonts folder, to be copied into a new folder. It all works fine except for Fonts containing spaces in the file title.
I feel like having tried all types of quotes on every location but nothing works. Can you help me here?

Comment: You put quotes around every path except for the one that you need it too.  `"%%f"`

Comment: Well, double quotes are also missing around wildcard pattern as `%UserProfile%` can expand to a path containing space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~`` as well. So the solution is: `for %%I in ("%UserProfile%\Fonts\*.*tf") do if not exist "%SystemRoot%\Fonts\%%~nxI" %SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%%I" "%UserProfile%\Fonts2\" /Y >nul`. Every argument string like a file name can be enclosed in double quotes, but those with a space or ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~<|>`` in argument string __must__ be enclosed in double quotes as help output on running `cmd.exe /?` in cmd window explains.